# Type annotation for using a F# TypeProvider type e.g. FSharp.Data.JsonProvider<...>.DomainTypes.Url

Tags: f#, type-providers, type-parameter, f#-data

I'm using the `FSharp.Data.JsonProvider` to read Twitter Tweets.

Playing with this sample code 
https://github.com/tpetricek/Documents/tree/master/Samples/Twitter.API

I want to expand the urls in the tweet with

```
let expandUrl (txt:string) (url:Search.DomainTypes<...>.DomainTypes.Url) = 
    txt.Replace( url.Url, url.ExpandedUrl )
```

This results in Error:

```
Lookup on object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. 
A type annotation may be needed prior to this program point to constrain the type of the object.
```

My problem is how to define the `TypeProvider` Type for url in the expandUrl function above?

The type inferance shows me this

```
val urls : FSharp.Data.JsonProvider<...>.DomainTypes.Url []
```

but this is not accepted in the type declaration. I assume "<...>" is not F# synatx.

How to do a type annotation for using a TypeProvider type e.g. `FSharp.Data.JsonProvider<...>.DomainTypes.Url ?`

Here is the complete code snippet:

```
open TwitterAPI // github.com/tpetricek/Documents/tree/master/Samples/Twitter.API 
let twitter = TwitterAPI.TwitterContext( _consumerKey, _consumerSecret, _accessToken, _accessTokenSecret )
let query = "water"
let ts = Twitter.Search.Tweets(twitter, Utils.urlEncode query, count=100)

let ret = 
  [ for x in ts.Statuses do
      // val urls : FSharp.Data.JsonProvider<...>.DomainTypes.Url []
      let urls = x.Entities.Urls 
      // fully declarated to help the type inference at expandUrl
      let replace (txt:string) (oldValue:string) (newValue:string) = 
          txt.Replace( oldValue, newValue)
      // Error:
      // Lookup on object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. 
      // A type annotation may be needed prior to this program point to constrain the type of the object. 
      // This may allow the lookup to be resolved.
      let expandUrl (txt:string) (url:FSharp.Data.JsonProvider<_>.DomainTypes.Url) = 
          replace txt url.Url url.ExpandedUrl
      let textWithExpandedUrls = Array.fold expandUrl x.Text urls
      yield textWithExpandedUrls
  ]
```

Comment: Yes <...> is not F# syntax, for generic types F# uses underscore <_>, however I don't think this applies here. Could you post a fragment of the JSON you are trying to parse?

Comment: I've already tried that. Then _  and  url.Url url.ExpandedUrl  gets red squiggles. It's also not possible to drill-down the type after FSharp.Data.JsonProvider by . "dot-browsing".

Comment: I added the link https://github.com/tpetricek/Documents/tree/master/Samples/Twitter.API to the code Im playing with to the question.

Comment: I added also the complete code snippet to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `Twitter.Search.Tweets` (https://github.com/tpetricek/Documents/blob/master/Samples/Twitter.API/Twitter.fs#L284), the return type of that is one of the domain types of `TwitterTypes.SearchTweets`, which is a type alias for `JsonProvider<"references\\search_tweets.json">` (https://github.com/tpetricek/Documents/blob/master/Samples/Twitter.API/Twitter.fs#L183).

Although in the tooltip it shows up as `JsonProvider<...>.DomainTypes.Url`, you'll have to use the type alias `TwitterTypes.SearchTweets.DomainTypes.Url`

Comment: Thank you, that works! 
Why is the type inference not able to show me the right tooltip? 
Or do i miss something.

Comment: Yes, that's probably something that could be improved

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem trying to figure out how to use the `FSharp.Data HtmlProvider`.

I am using Wikipedia to get information about USA [presidents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Presidents_of_the_United_States). The `HtmlProvider` does a great job of discovering the various tables in that webpage, but I wanted to extract the logic for processing a row of "president data" into a separate function called `processRow`.

And the problem was trying to work out what the type of such a row is for `processRow`'s parameter `row`. The following code does the trick:

```
#load "Scripts\load-references.fsx"

open FSharp.Data

let presidents = new HtmlProvider<"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Presidents_of_the_United_States">()

let ps = presidents.Tables.``List of presidents``

ps.Headers |> Option.map (fun hs -> for h in hs do printf "%s " h)

printfn ""

type Presidents = ``HtmlProvider,Sample="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Presidents_of_the_United_States"``.ListOfPresidents

let processRow (row:Presidents.Row) =
  printfn "%d %s" row.``№`` row.President2

ps.Rows |> Seq.iter processRow
```

I did not type in the long type alias for `Presidents`, I used Visual Studio auto-completion by guessing that the type for `List of presidents` would be discoverable from something starting with `Html`, and it was, complete with the four single back quotes.